# Transact SQL Skips GOTO or IF ELSE When a linked Server is in the code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I am trying to solve a problem ,"do not execute oracle query if server is unavailable", The Script checks the LINKED Server ORACLE is available and updates SQL Server with results Like below;

```
declare @srvr nvarchar(128), @retval int;
set @srvr = 'ORA_SVC';
begin try
  exec @retval = sys.sp_testlinkedserver @srvr;
end try
begin catch
  set @retval = sign(@@error);
end catch;
if @retval = 1 Update ORACLE_AVAIL set AVAILABLE = 0
if @retval = 0 Update ORACLE_AVAIL set AVAILABLE = 1
go
```

So... the above code works great!  And if I kill the ORACLE connection by modifying the TNSNames.ORA file...wait until the SQL server refreshes its connection the above code cannot find the linked server and updates the DB so we are good here.

After the GO above is this code and my problem.

```
DECLARE @ORACLE_ACTIVE BIT
set @ORACLE_ACTIVE = (select AVAILABLE from ORACLE_AVAIL)

if @ORACLE_ACTIVE = 1 GOTO ORACLE_IS_DOWN

INSERT into MY_SQL_SERVER_TABLE (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3)
select COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3 from ORA_SVC..ORA_SVC.ORACLE_TABLE 

ORACLE_IS_DOWN:
```

The above portion of my script will fail if the Oracle Server is offline, no matter the @Oracle_Avail If statement.

If I modify the code to;

```
DECLARE @ORACLE_ACTIVE BIT
set @ORACLE_ACTIVE = (select AVAILABLE from ORACLE_AVAIL)

if @ORACLE_ACTIVE = 1 GOTO ORACLE_IS_DOWN

PRINT 'GOTO DIDNT WORK'

ORACLE_IS_DOWN:
```

The Print Statement is ignored as expected. If @ORACLE_ACTIVE = 1 that is.

GOTO is bad, I get it.  IF ELSE will not work here either, if the linked server doesn't exist(the TNSNames.ora file points to an invalid host) the script will fail no matter the if @ORACLE_ACTIVE check.

Thanks for your time.
I really hope I worded this correctly, as I am not finding a solution via search Engines

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that during parsing, SQL Server tries to validate your query.  Perhaps it is trying to see if the columns exist.

You can defer parsing by moving the query to an inner scope:

```
exec N'INSERT into MY_SQL_SERVER_TABLE (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3)
       select COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3 from ORA_SVC..ORA_SVC.ORACLE_TABLE'
```

Comment: So Far, I have changed the query to use OPENQUERY assigned that to a variable and tried the EXEC method with-out the 'N' with the 'N' there is an error, even so, the script still errors and does not skip the intended portion if ORACLE is unavailable.  Thanks Andomar, I agree with your guess however, I need a better way to avoid attempting to execute scripts against a dead server.

Comment: Andomar, this is not an answer... Would you please remove it.  I really need an answer here.  Thanks

Comment: Your comment is short on details... what error?  is your oracle_active bit set correctly?  By the way, for renewed attention to your question, check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: Alas not enough points for bounties, thanks for the suggestion.
The Error is the FACT that even though the script return a ONE for the presence of the Oracle Servers existence;
    @Oracle_Active = 1
The script should move to the GOTO label thus bypassing the portion of the script that returns records from the linked server, IE 'DO NOT ATTEMPT TO QUERY ORACLE LINKED SERVER IF ORACLE LINKED SERVER IS UNAVAILABLE' Yet the script will Error in its attempt to query the OFFLINE Oracle Database, Does that explain the error?

Comment: So did you change your `insert` call to an `exec 'insert ...'` ?  Perhaps update your question (or post a new question) with the new query.